# if use @NotBlank or similar validation in my POJO class Spring-boot don't launch application

Tags: spring-boot, rest, validation

I am working on a project for a rest bees but when I go to insert the various validation for the fields of my pojo and start the application I receive this error:

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.nanosoft:agenda_studenti >--------------------
[INFO] Building agenda_studenti 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ agenda_studenti ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\workspace\java\agenda_nanosoft\target
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.3:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ agenda_studenti >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ agenda_studenti ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ agenda_studenti ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 14 source files to D:\workspace\java\agenda_nanosoft\target\classes
[INFO] /D:/workspace/java/agenda_nanosoft/src/main/java/com/nanosoft/agenda_studenti/AppuntamentiExceptionController.java: D:\workspace\java\agenda_nanosoft\src\main\java\com\nanosoft\agenda_studenti\AppuntamentiExceptionController.java uses or overrides a deprecated API that is marked for removal.
[INFO] /D:/workspace/java/agenda_nanosoft/src/main/java/com/nanosoft/agenda_studenti/AppuntamentiExceptionController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:removal for details.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ agenda_studenti ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\workspace\java\agenda_nanosoft\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ agenda_studenti ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\workspace\java\agenda_nanosoft\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.3:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ agenda_studenti <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.3:run (default-cli) @ agenda_studenti ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _   
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \  
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \ 
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / / 
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/  
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.3)

2023-02-25T15:37:24.624+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] c.n.a.AgendaStudentiApplication          : Starting AgendaStudentiApplication using Java 19.0.2 with PID 72852 (D:\workspace\java\agenda_nanosoft\target\classes started by gidan in D:\workspace\java\agenda_nanosoft)
2023-02-25T15:37:24.628+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] c.n.a.AgendaStudentiApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-02-25T15:37:25.207+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-02-25T15:37:25.265+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 45 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-02-25T15:37:25.755+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-02-25T15:37:25.773+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-02-25T15:37:25.774+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-02-25T15:37:25.938+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-25T15:37:25.942+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1260 ms
2023-02-25T15:37:26.110+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-02-25T15:37:26.264+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:d3f54f50-11bf-4fad-bf26-4613385de5e0 user=SA
2023-02-25T15:37:26.266+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-02-25T15:37:26.310+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo 
[name: default]
2023-02-25T15:37:26.354+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-02-25T15:37:26.595+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-02-25T15:37:27.223+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-02-25T15:37:27.232+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-02-25T15:37:27.539+01:00  WARN 72852 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning        
2023-02-25T15:37:27.895+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-02-25T15:37:27.903+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] c.n.a.AgendaStudentiApplication          : Started AgendaStudentiApplication in 3.582 seconds (process running for 3.896)
2023-02-25T15:37:27.962+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-02-25T15:37:27.978+01:00 ERROR 72852 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:772) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
        at com.nanosoft.agenda_studenti.AgendaStudentiApplication.main(AgendaStudentiApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:570) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:656) ~[spring-tx-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:409) ~[spring-tx-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]   
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]   
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]   
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]   
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5] 
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]   
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
        at com.nanosoft.agenda_studenti.$Proxy115.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.nanosoft.agenda_studenti.LoadDatabase.lambda$initDatabase$1(LoadDatabase.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]  
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:561) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: jakarta.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.time.LocalDate'. Check configuration for 'data'
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getExceptionForNullValidator(ConstraintTree.java:116) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:162) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:58) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:75) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:130) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:123) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:488) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:172) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final] 
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]     
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]        
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:612) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:483) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:729) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:480) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1425) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:477) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2234) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]  
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1930) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]       
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]  
        ... 22 common frames omitted

2023-02-25T15:37:28.020+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-02-25T15:37:28.022+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2023-02-25T15:37:28.025+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...      
2023-02-25T15:37:28.027+01:00  INFO 72852 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.        
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.684 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-02-25T15:37:28+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.3:run (default-cli) on project agenda_studenti: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is my POJO class:

```
package com.nanosoft.agenda_studenti;

import java.util.Objects;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.FutureOrPresent;

@Entity
class Appuntamenti {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @FutureOrPresent
    private LocalDate data;

    @NotBlank
    @FutureOrPresent
    private LocalTime ora;

    @NotBlank
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TipoAppuntamento tipo;

    @NotBlank
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Uffici ufficio;

    @NotBlank
    private String descrizione;

    Appuntamenti() {
    }

    Appuntamenti(LocalDate data, LocalTime ora, TipoAppuntamento tipo, Uffici ufficio, String descrizione) {
        this.data = data;
        this.ora = ora;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.ufficio = ufficio;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public LocalDate getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public LocalTime getOra() {
        return this.ora;
    }

    public Uffici getUfficio() {
        return this.ufficio;
    }

    public TipoAppuntamento getTipoAppuntamento() {
        return this.tipo;
    }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return this.descrizione;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setData(LocalDate data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setOra(LocalTime ora) {
        this.ora = ora;
    }

    public void setTipoAppuntamento(TipoAppuntamento tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public void setUfficio(Uffici ufficio) {
        this.ufficio = ufficio;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o)
            return true;

        if (!(o instanceof Appuntamenti))
            return false;

        Appuntamenti appuntamenti = (Appuntamenti) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, appuntamenti.id) && Objects.equals(this.data, appuntamenti.data)
                && Objects.equals(this.ora, appuntamenti.ora)
                && Objects.equals(this.tipo, appuntamenti.tipo) && Objects.equals(this.ufficio, appuntamenti.ufficio)
                && Objects.equals(this.descrizione, appuntamenti.descrizione);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.id, this.data, this.ora, this.tipo, this.ufficio, this.descrizione);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Appuntamento{" + "id=" + this.id + ", data=" + this.data + ", ora='" + this.ora
                + "', tipo_appuntamento='" + this.tipo
                + "', ufficio='" + this.ufficio + "', descrzione='" + this.descrizione + "'}";
    }
}
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nanosoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>agenda_studenti</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>agenda_studenti</name>
    <description>Esercizio sulla creazione di API per gestire l'agenda di uno studente</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

if i put the @valid only in my controller the app lauch smootly. This is my controller:

```
package com.nanosoft.agenda_studenti;

import java.util.List;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.hateoas.CollectionModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.*;
import org.springframework.hateoas.IanaLinkRelations;

@RestController
public class AppuntamentiController {

    private final AppuntamentiRepository repository;
    private final AppuntamentiModelAssembler assembler;

    AppuntamentiController(AppuntamentiRepository repository, AppuntamentiModelAssembler assembler) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.assembler = assembler;
    }

    // Aggregate root
    // tag::get-aggregate-root[]
    @GetMapping("/appuntamenti")
    CollectionModel<EntityModel<Appuntamenti>> all() {

        List<EntityModel<Appuntamenti>> appuntamenti = repository.findAll().stream().map(assembler::toModel)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return CollectionModel.of(appuntamenti, linkTo(methodOn(AppuntamentiController.class).all()).withSelfRel());
    }
    // end::get-aggregate-root[]

    // inserisci appuntamento
    @PostMapping("appuntamenti")
    ResponseEntity<?> newAppuntamenti(@RequestBody @Valid Appuntamenti newAppuntamenti) {

        EntityModel<Appuntamenti> entityModel = assembler.toModel(repository.save(newAppuntamenti));

        return ResponseEntity.created(entityModel.getRequiredLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF).toUri()).body(entityModel);
    }

    // appuntamenti per data
    @GetMapping("appuntamenti/data")
    CollectionModel<EntityModel<Appuntamenti>> perData(@RequestParam @Valid LocalDate data) {

        List<EntityModel<Appuntamenti>> l = repository.findByDataOrderByOraAsc(data).stream().map(assembler::toModel)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (l.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AppuntamentoPerDataNotFoundException("Non ho trovato appuntamenti per il giorno " + data);
        }
        return CollectionModel.of(l, linkTo(methodOn(AppuntamentiController.class).perData(data)).withSelfRel());
    }

    // appuntamenti per ufficio
    @GetMapping("appuntamenti/ufficio")
    CollectionModel<EntityModel<Appuntamenti>> perTipoAppuntamento(@RequestParam @Valid TipoAppuntamento tipo) {

        List<EntityModel<Appuntamenti>> l = repository.findByTipoAppuntamentiOrderByDataAndOraAsc(tipo).stream()
                .map(assembler::toModel).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (l.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AppuntamentoPerTipoAppuntamentiNotFoundException("Non ho trovato appuntamenti di tipo: " + tipo);
        }
        return CollectionModel.of(l,
                linkTo(methodOn(AppuntamentiController.class).perTipoAppuntamento(tipo)).withSelfRel());
    }

    // appuntamento per data e ora
    @GetMapping("appuntamenti/")
    EntityModel<Appuntamenti> appuntamentoSpecifico(@RequestParam @Valid LocalDate data,
            @RequestParam @Valid LocalTime ora) {

        Appuntamenti a = repository.findByDataAndOra(data, ora);
        if (a == null) {
            throw new AppuntamentoPerDataOraNotFoundException(
                    "Non ho trovato l'appuntamento per il giorno " + data + " alle ore " + ora);
        }
        return assembler.toModel(a);
    }

    // appuntamenti per descrizione
    @GetMapping("appuntamenti/descrizione")
    CollectionModel<EntityModel<Appuntamenti>> perDescrizione(@RequestParam @Valid String descrizione) {

        List<EntityModel<Appuntamenti>> l = repository.findByDescrizioneOrderByDataAscAndOraAsc(descrizione).stream()
                .map(assembler::toModel).collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (l.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AppuntamentoPerDescrizioneNotFoundException(
                    "Non ho trovato appuntamenti contenente tutta o parte di questa descizione '" + descrizione + "'");
        }
        return CollectionModel.of(l,
                linkTo(methodOn(AppuntamentiController.class).perDescrizione(descrizione)).withSelfRel());

    }

    @PutMapping("appuntamenti/put")
    ResponseEntity<?> replaceAppuntamentoAppuntamento(@RequestBody @Valid Appuntamenti newAppuntamento,
            @RequestParam LocalDate data,
            @RequestParam LocalTime ora) {

        Appuntamenti findedAppuntamento = repository.findByDataAndOra(data, ora);

        if (findedAppuntamento != null) {
            findedAppuntamento.setData(newAppuntamento.getData());
            findedAppuntamento.setOra(newAppuntamento.getOra());
            findedAppuntamento.setTipoAppuntamento(newAppuntamento.getTipoAppuntamento());
            findedAppuntamento.setUfficio(newAppuntamento.getUfficio());
            findedAppuntamento.setDescrizione(newAppuntamento.getDescrizione());

            EntityModel<Appuntamenti> entityModel = assembler.toModel(repository.save(findedAppuntamento));

            return ResponseEntity.created(entityModel.getRequiredLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF).toUri())
                    .body(entityModel);
        }

        EntityModel<Appuntamenti> entityModel = assembler.toModel(repository.save(newAppuntamento));

        return ResponseEntity.created(entityModel.getRequiredLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF).toUri()).body(entityModel);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/appuntamenti/delete")
    void deleteAppuntamento(@RequestParam @Valid LocalDate data, @RequestParam @Valid LocalTime ora) {
        repository.deleteByDataAndOra(data, ora);
    }
}
```

EDIT: add repository

```
package com.nanosoft.agenda_studenti;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;

@Repository
@Transactional
interface AppuntamentiRepository extends JpaRepository<Appuntamenti, Long> {
//query here
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Could you please show me the repository layer and properties file?

Comment: added repository

Comment: Now you can remove the @Trancactional from the repository, because you are not used it.

Comment: Even after removing it, it still gives the error

Comment: Also you need to change date time from (import java.time.LocalDate)  to(import java.sql.Date).

Comment: but i need both LocalDate and LocalTime

Comment: you can see this link: https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-localdate-sql-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the exception you receive is self-explainable:

> jakarta.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.time.LocalDate'. Check configuration for 'data'

```java
@NotBlank
@FutureOrPresent
private LocalDate data;
```

you can't apply `@NotBlank` constraint to non-charsequence fields, just because `@NotBlank` constraint [is not designed for that](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.0/apidocs/index.html?jakarta/validation/constraints/NotBlank.html):

> The annotated element must not be null and must contain at least one non-whitespace character. **Accepts CharSequence**.

Use `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` instead.

Comment: ok i fixed that but now it gives me this:
Caused by: jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.nanosoft.agenda_studenti.Appuntamenti] during persist 
time for groups [jakarta.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='deve essere una data nel presente o nel futuro', propertyPath=ora, rootBeanClass=class com.nanosoft.agenda_studenti.Appuntamenti, messageTemplate='{jakarta.validation.constraints.FutureOrPresent.message}'}

Comment: what behaviour did you expect when placing `@FutureOrPresent` constraint over entity fields?

Comment: I want the entered value to be greater than or equal to now or that it is at least in the future since it is the date and time of an appointment

Comment: update: the problem is when I try to validate the LocalTime field with @ Future or @ FutureOrPresent